# Trying to get data via related table in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.4, relationship

What I'm trying to do is to show the posts that have been saved by the user in the profile. I will try to explain it as good as possible refering to my code. So:

```
public function userProfil($id)
```

I have the profile function which get the data from userprofile table. and inside I have the following code for saved data:

```
$authed = User::find($id);
$savedarticles = $authed->mysaves;
$allsavings = DB::select("Select * from article where id=$savedarticles->id");
```

But this code does not work like this anyway. I can do this instead:

```
$authed = User::find($id);
$savedarticles = $authed->mysaves;
```

But when I try to get articles from article table with the article_id of mysaves, it does not work such as this:

```
$allsaved= DB::table('article')->where('id', $savedarticles->article_id);
```

the error it gives is like:

> Property [article_id] does not exist on this collection instance.

although savearticle table has `article_id` I can output it without the line above and in view I get them as:

```
@foreach($savedarticles as $savedarticle)
    <p>{{$savedarticle}}</p>
@endforeach
```

it gives me everything that is in the savearticle table and I can get do `savedarticle->article_id` and get `article_id` but can't get it in controller.

I am using Laravel 5.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message `Property [article_id] does not exist on this collection instance.` means you are trying to get an attribute of a single instance but from a collection.

For example the collection could be like

```
[$article1, $article2, $article3]
```

therefore what you tried to do is something similar to

```
[$article1, $article2, $article3]->article_id
```

You are trying to get an attribute from a collection instead of a single instance.

As for your query, you can use `where in` sql statement to search for rows that match any item in an array

```
$allsaved= DB::table('article')->whereIn('id', $savedarticles->pluck('article_id')->all());
```

Comment: throws error `Call to a member function pluck() on array`

Comment: i dont know when it became an array but you probably made changes to your code after `$savedarticles = $authed->mysaves;`

Comment: aaaaahhh yeaaah I did :D Let me try this around again

Comment: I tried to turn stuff back, the error now I get is ***htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given (View: C:\wamp64\www\yazilimhaber\resources\views\userProfil.blade.php)***

Answer (score 0):

What I have understood is that A USER has many POSTS and a POST belong to an article.

If this is true then you have to do following.

1: In USER model define a relation to get all posts. like below.

```
public function posts() {
   // Foreign key will be a key that is stored in posts table and represent the user MAY BE: user_id
   $this->hasMany(Posts::class, 'foreign_key', 'local_key')
}
```

This will allow you to get all posts belong to a user.

2: In posts, model defines a user relation like below.

```
public function user() {
   $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
}
```

This will allow you to get a post User;

3: Now in your controller you will have something like this.

```
public function show($user_id) {

      // find a user with posts as eager loading(to avoid query again)
      $user = User::with(['posts'])->where('id', $user_id)->first();

      // get all posts that belong to this user
      $posts = $user->posts; 
   }
```

In controller show($user_id) method you will have a user data as well as user posts data. Now if you want to get a post relations then simply define as below. let say a post belongs to an article as well.

4: In posts, model defines a relation to get an article.

```
public function article() {
  // This will allow you to get a post artcle
  $this->belongsTo(Article::class, 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
}
```

Now you can get the article as well while finding a user. please see below. I am rewriting controller show action to give you a better understanding.

5: Get a user with user_id

```
public function show($user_id) {

// find a user with posts as eager loading(to avoid query again)
// eager loading for posts & post child, this will give you NOSQL at runtime and all data will come from one query. 
          $user = User::with(['posts', 'posts.article'])->where('id', $user_id)->first();

          // get all posts that belong to this user
          $posts = $user->posts; 
foreach($posts as $post) {
  $article = $post->article; // Child relation of post. 
}

   }
```

Hope you will understand the flow, you have to make sure models relation to work it perfectly. If you need further help please let me know.

Comment: well it's pretty close what I was trying to tell except. the user has savedarticles not posts, and savedarticles is used to store the article_id and user_id. than when user trying to see saved articles in it's profile I will need to get article_id from savearticle table where user_id is the id I send in, and than I will get articles from article table equal to the article_id I have in save article. but the logic you made here is going to work both way, I will try to make connection.

Comment: I dont't understan what excactly this line is supposed to do `$user = User::with(['posts', 'posts.article'])->where('id', $user_id)->first();`

Comment: especially `'posts.article'])->where('id', $user_id)`

Comment: it is more like a user has SAVED ARTICLES and a USER may save many ARTICLES.

Comment: ok now everything works as it's suppoesd to do until the `foreach`, Do you any idea what might be the reason? BTW I'm not sure `$article` is gonna give me, a single row or all the posts? should i use foreach to output the result in view or just the $article right away?

Comment: @Nikonah I am just giving you an example how you can get relation and relation of relation.

Like a user have many posts and each post belong to an article. so above query allow you to get posts & Article in single query.